# Maven: Warning if dependency if artefact is not found

Tags: maven, maven-2

Can I add option to Maven to say WARNING if some artefact wasn't found in some repository. Let's I have

```
<repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>main</id>
         <name>main-repo</name>
         <url>http://repourl</url>
         <layout>default</layout>
         <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
         </releases>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
         </snapshots>
      </repository>
   </repositories>
```

But Maven not find some dependency of dependency in repo. Then he say WARNING in log. Can I do it?

A have in my company's repo resource 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:pom:2.5.4'. But I havn't dependencies. This resource was copied to my JAR file. But no one dependency of 'cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs' wasn't intsalled. In log

```
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:pom:2.5.4' in repository MAIN (http://url/)
Downloading: http://url//org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs/2.5.4/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.5.4.pom
```

But no warning about dependencies of **cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs**

Comment: Usually it will break the build if it does not find an artifact...may be i misunderstand the question?

Comment: Break if Dependency not found. But if Dependency of Dependency not found - build passed well! It's wrong!

Comment: Do you have a real example? log output ?

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your company repo (i hope you are using a repository manager aren't you?) cause i can find it in maven central (http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.cxf|cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs|2.5.4|jar). You check the logs of your repository...

Comment: Yep! It's problem of my company repo, and problem has already resolved. But if I saw warning, problem was be fixed early! So, can Maven say Warning in this case?

Comment: The problem in that case seemed to be that this pom is not used directly...Have you configured the repositories in your settings.xml or in the pom?

Comment: And setting.xml, and parent pom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependencies of cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs are declared in org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:pom:2.5.4 artifact, which Maven was not able to find. So, answer to your question is it can't be done.